# Show all categories for each partition even if no data exists

Tags: sql, join, amazon-athena

I have 2 tables, one is showing some values per date, store, type and product like this (this is already GROUP BY date, store, type, product):

Table 1:

| date | store | type | product | values | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7/1 | s1 | A | a | 1 | ... |
| 7/1 | s1 | A | b | 2 | ... |
| 7/2 | s1 | B | d | 3 | ... |
| 7/2 | s2 | A | c | 4 | ... |

The second is a list of all possible types and products:

Table 2:

| type | product |
| --- | --- |
| A | a |
| A | b |
| A | c |
| B | d |

Now I want to join this two table to show all possible types/products per date and store, so the result would be:

| date | store | type | product | values | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7/1 | s1 | A | a | 1 | ... |
| 7/1 | s1 | A | b | 2 | ... |
| 7/1 | s1 | A | c | 0 | ... |
| 7/1 | s1 | B | d | 0 | ... |
| 7/2 | s1 | A | a | 0 | ... |
| 7/2 | s1 | A | b | 0 | ... |
| 7/2 | s1 | A | c | 0 | ... |
| 7/2 | s1 | B | d | 3 | ... |
| 7/2 | s1 | A | a | 0 | ... |
| 7/2 | s1 | A | b | 0 | ... |
| 7/2 | s2 | A | c | 4 | ... |
| 7/2 | s1 | B | d | 0 | ... |

I've tried doing a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT t1.date, t1.store. t1.values, t2.type, t2.product
FROM t2 
LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.type = t2.type, t1.product = t2.product
```

But this is not giving me the expected output, it only work if one type is not in t1 at all.

What would be the correct way to do so?

Comment: `per date and store` is a possibly infinite set. Please clarify the range for this combination.

Comment: What do you mean by infinite? So I may have say 30 days data, and 10 stores. I would like for each day each store, it shows all type and products. Is this achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query shows all combinations of `(type, product)` in `tbl2` for all combinations of `(date, store)` in `tbl1`:

```sql
SELECT ds.*, t2.*, t1.value
FROM  (
   SELECT date, store
   FROM   tbl1
   GROUP  BY date, store
   ) AS ds
CROSS  JOIN tbl2 AS t2
LEFT   JOIN tbl1 AS t1 USING (date, store, type, product);
```

Alternatively, you can replace the subquery `ds` with the full set of combinations for

> 30 days data, and 10 stores

(Like when `tbl1` does not contain data for all combinations.)

`value` will be NULL if no row is found in `tbl1`. You can use `COALESCE(t1.value, 0)` to get `0` instead.